# MVVM Single Activity app return to a nested fragment with Navigation component after leaving app or launching intent

Tags: android, android-fragments, mvvm, androidx, android-jetpack

I am trying to return to a specific fragment after pressing the home button, sharing data with another app or switching activities.

Fragments in bottomNav:

**A B C D**

Fragments that are shared around the app and can be nested or navigated to from the bottomNav fragments:

**E F G**

Intended behaviour

User navigation stack:

**A -> E**

Presses home button and reopens app, stack remains the same.

**A -> E**

Actual Behaviour

User navigation stack:

**A -> E**

Presses home button and reopens app, brought back to first fragment

**A**

I tried to restore the navigation state by passing a bundle from `navController.saveState()` to a viewmodel during the Main Activity **onPause** method and restoring it with `navController.restoreState()` **onResume** to no avail. Is this not capable with the navigation component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is called `Multiple Backstack`. Every `Fragment` in android maintains its own stack. So if you navigate to another `Fragment` in the `ParentFragment`, your `ParentFragment` will add the `childFragment` in its stack.
In your case, your `ParentFragment` is `A` and `childFragment` is E.

However, `NavigationComponent` has no vanilla support for `Multiple Backstack`. Ian Lake, the creator of `NavigationComponent` library is working on this issue since `NavigationComponent` was launched, and still haven't delivered on it. This doesn't mean he is not working on it, it simply means (as stated by Ian himself) that its harder to achieve because of `Fragments` API.

Coming back to your question, if you really want to implement `MultipleBackstack` then you can follow this [project](https://github.com/moallemi/MultiNavHost) which pretty much anyone who wants `MultipleBackstack` with `NavigationComponent` first refers to. There is also a [google sample](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/blob/master/NavigationAdvancedSample/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/navigationadvancedsample/NavigationExtensions.kt) that shows how to achieve this behavior.